# symfony 2 twig limit the length of the text and put three dots

Tags: symfony, twig

How can I limit the length of the text, e.g., 50, and put three dots in the display?

```
{% if myentity.text|length > 50 %}

{% block td_text %} {{ myentity.text}}{% endblock %}

{%endif%}
```

Comment: The "three dots" is actually a single character called an Ellipsis. This is three full stops `...` and this is an Ellipsis `…`

Answer (score 234):

```
{{ myentity.text|length > 50 ? myentity.text|slice(0, 50) ~ '...' : myentity.text  }}
```

You need [Twig 1.6](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/slice.html)

Comment: this should be the answer, still working till now ;)

Comment: How can we add a link to ... ?

Comment: Additionally, if you want to crop on a word, you can do it like this: `{{ text > 50 ? text|slice(0, 51)|split(' ')|slice(0, -1)|join(' ') ~ '…' : text }}`. I also recommend using the ellipsis character (`…`) instead of 3 real dots (`...`)

Comment: Shorter: `{{ myentity.text[:50] ~ (myentity.text|length > 50 ? '...') }}`

Comment: @Nemo64 you're just missing the `|length` after the first `text` but that's perfect, thank you!

Comment: Yes don't forget "|length" {{ text|length > 50 ? text|slice(0, 51)|split(' ')|slice(0, -1)|join(' ') ~ '…' : text }}

Comment: Thanks it works
{{ item.text|length > 50 ? item.text|slice(0, 50) ~ '...' : item.text  }}

Comment: @martias reply above (the shorter option) worked well for me. Drupal 8.6.

Answer (score 128):

why not use twig's truncate or wordwrap filter? It belongs to [twig extensions](https://github.com/fabpot/Twig-extensions) and lib is part of Symfony2.0 as i see.

```
{{ text|truncate(50) }}
```

Comment: I'm using Symfony 2.3 and the truncate filter is not part of the default extensions. Therefore, I resorted to Manuel's solution instead.

Comment: To enable the extension in Symfony add this to one of your configuration files: https://gist.github.com/pschultz/f33bfff72692ca0b6916

Comment: To append `...`,  the second parameter should be set to `true` such as `{{ text|truncate(50, true)`

Comment: Actually setting the second parameter to true would make it preserve whole words. It adds the ellipses by default. The third parameter can change the ellipses to anything you want. http://twig-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/text.html#truncating-text

Comment: Using Symfony 2.8, I had to install this extension to use it. ```require twig/extensions```

Answer (score 39):

Another one is:

```
{{ myentity.text[:50] ~ '...' }}
```

Comment: the only problem is that it always shows the dots... :/ think i will go with the first solution.

Comment: Please, can you share the link where the doc about this [x:x] is located ?

Comment: Always with the three dots there... doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score 21):

I know this is a very old question, but from twig 1.6 you can use the slice filter;

```
{{ myentity.text|slice(0, 50) ~ '...' }}
```

The second part from the tilde is optional for if you want to add something for example the ellipsis.

**Edit:** My bad, I see the most up-voted answer do make use of the slice filter.

Answer (score 16):

Update for Twig 2 and Twig 3.

truncate filter is not available, instead of it you may use [u-filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/u.html)

here is an example:

```
{{ 'Lorem ipsum'|u.truncate(8) }}
Lorem ip

{{ 'Lorem ipsum'|u.truncate(8, '...') }}
Lorem...
```

Note: this filter is part of StringExtension that can be required by

```
twig/string-extra
```

Comment: Had to add     
```Twig\Extra\String\StringExtension: null```
in the twig_extensions.yaml

Comment: Yes.    composer require twig/string-extra

Answer (score 14):

@olegkhuss solution with named UTF-8 Elipsis:

`{{ (my.text|length > 50 ? my.text|slice(0, 50) ~ '…' : my.text)  }}`

Comment: Please keep in mind this solution enables HTML injection through the `text` variable.

Comment: @michael-zukowski Your are right. I have changed my solution.

Answer (score 10):

@mshobnr / @olegkhuss solution made into a simple macro:

```
{% macro trunc(txt, len) -%}
    {{ txt|length > len ? txt|slice(0, len) ~ '…' : txt }}
{%- endmacro %}
```

Usage example:

```
{{ tools.trunc('This is the text to truncate. ', 50) }}
```

N.b. I import a Twig template containing macros and import it as 'tools' like this (Symfony):

```
{% import "@AppBundle/tools.html.twig" as tools -%}
```

Also, I replaced the html character code with the actual character, this should be no problem when using UTF-8 as the file encoding. This way you don't have to use `|raw` (as it could cause a security issue).

Answer (score 7):

Use the truncate filter to cut off a string after limit is reached

```
{{ "Hello World!"|truncate(5) }} // default separator is ...
```

> Hello...

You can also tell truncate to preserve whole words by setting the second parameter to true. If the last Word is on the the separator, truncate will print out the whole Word.

```
 {{ "Hello World!"|truncate(7, true) }} // preserve words
```

> Here Hello World!

If you want to change the separator, just set the third parameter to your desired separator.

```
{{ "Hello World!"|truncate(7, false, "??") }}
```

> Hello W??

Answer (score 6):

An even more elegant solution is to limit the text by the number of words (and not by number of characters). This prevents ugly tear throughs (e.g. 'Stackov...').

Here's an example where I shorten only text blocks longer than 10 words:

```
{% set text = myentity.text |split(' ') %} 

{% if text|length > 10 %} 
    {% for t in text|slice(0, 10) %}
        {{ t }} 
    {% endfor %}
    ...
{% else %}
    {{ text|join(' ') }}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can limit in following way. First is starting index and second is number of characters.

```
**{{ results['text'][4:2] }}**
```

Answer (score 1):

if anyone needs this from the  modern world, since this question is so old, I would do it this way: I would definitely not want to have an incomplete word at the end, therefor I prefer to do it with the following steps:
limiting the wanted length of characters, exploid my text into a bunch of arrays of sentences separated with a comma or a dot depends on your text, remove the last array which represent the incomplete word then joining or imploiding those arrays together and of course do not forget to join them with that dot we removed when exploiding the string of characters, and outside of the twig {{}} add your three dots, with that been said it will look something like this:

`{{myentity.text|slice(0,50)|split('.')|slice(0,-1)|join('.')}}...`

`<a href="#">readeMore</a>`

Comment: Only prints out "..." whenever the text doesn't have a dot in the first 50 characters, it seems.

Answer (score 1):

`u.truncate` could be a modern option.
An example from [docs](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/u.html):

```
{{ 'Lorem ipsum dolor'|u.truncate(10, '...', false) }}
Lorem ipsum...
```

This solution requires [string-extra](https://github.com/twigphp/string-extra):

```bash
composer require twig/string-extra
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this simple marco for the same purpose, hope it helps:

```
{%- macro stringMaxLength(str, maxLength) -%}
    {%- if str | length < maxLength -%}
        {{ str }}
    {%- else -%}
        {{ str|slice(0, maxLength) }}...
    {%- endif -%}
{%- endmacro -%}
```

Usage Example #1 (Output: "my long string here ..."):

```
{{ _self.stringMaxLength("my long string here bla bla bla la", 20) }}
```

Usage Example #2 (Output: "shorter string!"):

```
{{ _self.stringMaxLength("shorter string!", 20) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bugginess* in the new Drupal 8 capabilities here inspired us to write our own:

```
<a href="{{ view_node }}">{% if title|length > 32 %}{% set title_array = title|split(' ') %}{% set title_word_count = 0 %}{% for ta in title_array %}{% set word_count = ta|length %}{% if title_word_count < 32 %}{% set title_word_count = title_word_count + word_count %}{{ ta }} {% endif %}{% endfor %}...{% else %}{{ title }}{% endif %}</a>
```

This takes into consideration both words and characters (*the "word boundary" setting in D8 was displaying nothing).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Nemo64's comment under olegkhuss's [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13143106/7058317), I'd like to add that if you need to make the partial text to finishes on a word not a character, u can do this:

```
entity.text|split(' ', 11)|length > 10 ? entty.text|split(' ', 11)|slice(0, 10)|join(' ') ~ '…' : entity.text
```

In this example, all text with more than 10 words will be cuted after the 10th word.

Answer (score -1):

It is better to use an HTML character

```
{{ entity.text[:50] }}&#8230;
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your answer? Why should one use a HTML entity? And why do you append it to the text in each and every case, even if the text is less than 50 characters long?

Comment: Hi, if you write three dots it's three separate dots but the "three dots" character is called an ellipsis. The ellipsis html entity is `&#8230;`.

Comment: And why not use the unicode character for that ellipsis?

Comment: You can use it too ! this comment was an answer to that comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/17118915/5923187 but that move was locked because of my reputation