# How to show few lines of o large paragraph with symfony3.4 from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, symfony-3.4

How to show few lines of a large paragraph in a table.
The following code shows all of the lines and they can't place in table correctly.

**index.html.twig**

```
    {% for new in news %}
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{ new.id }}</th>
        <td>{{ new.topic }}</td>
        <td>{{ new.article }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13143001/symfony-2-twig-limit-the-length-of-the-text-and-put-three-dots ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, mention a class name for your td tag,

for example

```
<td class="article"></td>
```

In which you are limiting number of characters to show.

and put this script in your file and your code will look something like this
**For limiting article section ->**

```
{% for new in news %}
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{ new.id }}</th>
        <td>{{ new.topic }}</td>
        <td class="article">{{ new.article }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Now include this script in your file

```
<script>
    $(".article").text(function(index, currentText) {
        return currentText.substr(0, 50); // You can change 50 to as many characters, you want to display
    });
</script>
```

I am assuming that you are using jquery library, 
Hope It helps...